# posts_per_page is not working by term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I'm trying to limit the posts, but it does not work. It shows them all.

Why `posts_per_page` does not work here?

```
<?php // Output all Taxonomies names with their respective items
$terms = get_terms( 'genres' );
foreach( $terms as $term ):
?>
    <h3><?php echo $term->name; // Print the term name ?></h3>
    <ul>
        <?php
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 1, 
            'taxonomy'       => $term->taxonomy,
            'term'           => $term->slug,                                  
        ) );
        foreach ( $posts as $post):  // begin cycle through posts of this taxonmy
            setup_postdata( $post ); // set up post data for use in the loop (enables the_title(), etc without specifying a post ID)
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: could possibly be an external interference, usually its the `pre_get_posts` hook, try add this `remove_action('pre_get_posts')` before `$terms = get_terms( 'genres' );`

Comment: @CraigWayne it does not work, it also shows an error

Warning: Missing argument 2 for remove_action(), called in front-page.php on line 228 and defined in wp-includes\plugin.php on line 554

Comment: Try comment out this line in `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:1634`, it should be the line that has `do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );`

let me know if that helps, otherwise, try disabling all your plugins

Comment: it does not work, and the only plugin I have is contact form 7

Comment: Where is this code located and how is it being called? Your post loop is inside another loop,  are you expecting to only see a single post on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the tax query in wrong way. Please use     `'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => '$term->taxonomy', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => '$term->slug' ) ),`

instead of  `'taxonomy'       => $term->taxonomy, 'term'           => $term->slug,`

It will work fine.

Comment: Hi Moshsin it still does not work.

Comment: Can you please provide your latest code after the changes you have made.

Comment: Please also check your code with the default wordpress theme without any third party plugins. May be there is a code in the third party plugin or in the theme that changes the number of posts.